# How to debug angular application in Visual Studio Code not using chrome developer tools?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Currently I am debugging using developer tools of Chrome browser, but that is inconvenient.In the sources tab it only shows core.js, vendor.js, zone.js etc. not the typescript files.I have to add console.log, then that shows up in console tab, along with source typescript file, clicking on link opens up source file in source tab & I am able to set breakpoints.
But I do not want to do it that way.I want to do it from inside Visual Source Code.When I open the folder, it automatically creates a launch.json in .vscode as below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
        "name": "Launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/index.js",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "args": [],
        "runtimeExecutable": null,
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy"
        ],
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        "console": "internalConsole",
        "sourceMaps": false
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 5858
    }]
}
```

But when I run the code in debug mode, I cannot set any break-point as VSC tells me 'break-point set but not yet bound' and basically debugging does not work.
I have installed Chrome extension in VSC. I have tried to add launch configuration of type chrome, but that has not worked as below:

```
{
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Angular version 7.1.0
Visual Studio Code: 1.41.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **debugger** keyword in your typescript function. If the code inspector on any browser is open, the execution will stop at the place were **debugger** is mentioned and from there you can manually go ahead line by line.

Edit: If you're doing this, make sure all debuggers are removed before the application goes to staging or production environments.

Comment: I used debugger statement in typescript code. But my intention is not to use Chrome developer tools, which I have to still depend on.